# grabbing the last last id based on user_name - codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter

I'm working on a project that has one main article and you can attach many different articles to it. So on submit I have broken the article from into two different sections, since I need them to submit into two different tables.

After submitting the first part, I'm trying to get the last submitted id based on their user_name so I can attach the rest of the article. If that makes sense.

I've tried several different things, but nothing seems to grab back that id.

First I tried the insert_id() meathod, but that returns a 0

```
public function pullLastStoryId($author){
    $this->db->where('author', $author);
    $this->db->insert_id();
    $story = $this->db->get('story_tbl');
    return $story->result();    
}
```

So then I also tried just grabbing

```
public function pullLastStoryId($author){
    $story = $this->db->query('SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() INTO story_tbl;')
    return $story->result();    
}
```

Any idea's

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear with the question. Are you looking for something like this?

```
public function pullLastStoryId(){
    $story = $this->db->query('SELECT id from tablename where id = LAST_INSERT_ID()')
    return $story->result();    
}
```

OR

```
public function pullLastStoryId(){
    $id = $this->db->insert_id();
    $this->db->where('id',$id);
    $story = $this->db->get('story_tbl');
    return $story->result();    
}
```

Comment: Not really, I'm trying to get back the last inserted article id based on who the author is, my unique field is the author since no one can have the same user_name.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are talking about a foreign-key relationship between two tables. One way to do this would be something like:

```
$this->db->insert('author',$vals);
$id = $this->db->insert_id();
// do something with ID.
```

From what I can tell, you would probably then do something like this:

```
$story_row = $this->db->get_where('story_tbl',array('id' => $id));
```

You should not have to worry about different `user_name` property, because that will be last created ID. If you really wanted to get that row back, though, you could do this:

```
$author_row = $this->db->get_where('author',array('author_id' => $id));
```

If you need to have this ID somewhere else (say, after another form is submitted), you can either use a `hidden` form input or (this is a bit more secure), you can store that ID in session.

Comment: This actually won't work for me. I think you misunderstood my question. I'm not inserting anything or trying to get back the author. I'm trying to get back the last inserted article based on the author's user name so they can insert the rest of the article.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get Last id, your way is wrong. $this->db->insert_id() or etc for active query. Try this: SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

Comment: The major reason to use sequences, `auto_increment` etc. for ID's is that the DB is far better at preserving integrity. What would you do if someone managed an insert from a separate request at the same time?